# Is it posible to insert value in a model containing two foreign key?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with two foreign key and I want to insert the values in one row.
The model for example is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from cms.models.authUser import AuthUser
from cms.models.masterCmsUserTypes import MasterCmsUserTypes

class MasterCmsUser(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser,db_column='userId')
    userTypeId = models.ForeignKey(MasterCmsUserTypes,  db_column='userTypeId')
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    isDelete = models.BooleanField(db_column="isDelete", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")
    idv2 = models.IntegerField(db_column='idV2')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'master_cms_user'
```

This is my views:

```
@login_required
def admin_user_add(request):
    try:
        master_cms_user_type_list =MasterCmsUserTypes.objects.all()
        first_name = request.POST.get('firstName')
        last_name = request.POST.get('lastName')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        confirmPassword = request.POST.get('confirmPassword')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        status = request.POST.get('status')
        userTypeId = request.POST.get('userType')
        if status is None or status == '':
            status = False
        else:
            status = True
        staff=False
        superUser=False
        if password != confirmPassword:
                messages.error(request,'Password and Confirm Password must be same')
        if request.method =='POST':
            authUser = AuthUser(firstName=first_name,lastName=last_name,password=password,username=username,email=email,
                                isActive=status,isStaff=staff,isSuperuser=superUser)
            authUser.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully added to the university list')
            print authUser.id
            authid = int(authUser.id)
            # ci= get_object_or_404(AuthUser, id=authUser.id)
            # print authid
            # myu_admin_user = AuthUser.objects.get(id=authid)
            # print myu_admin_user
            cmsStatus=True
            cmsDelete=False
            masterCmsUser = MasterCmsUser(userId=authid,userTypeId=userTypeId,status=cmsStatus,isDelete=cmsDelete)
            masterCmsUser.save()


        return render(request, 'templates/admin_user_management/admin_user_add.html',{
            'master_cms_user_type_list':master_cms_user_type_list
            })
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        raise Http404
```

now when I removed my froeign key constrain the values are successfully inserted into table. But, when I have foreign key it ask for instance of that table which has foreign key bound.

Comment: Er, yes, of course it's possible. What have you tried, and where were you having difficulties?

Comment: yes its possible. but more than this we cannot help you, because you need to try and then ask if you get stuck somewhere

Comment: Quick tip: don't name foreign keys in django like `userId`. It is id in a table, but when you use this field it acts like user object. And you don't need to explicitly set `db_column`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I have done this way and it is working but what if I want foreign constraint should be present and then I insert the values

Comment: Not related to your question, but as I've told you before, you need to *stop* doing this catch-all try/except and then raising 404. Just don't do it. For a start, 404 is the wrong result for an error; but in any case, Django will already handle any errors if you let it. Just remove the try/except.

Comment: kk sir @DanielRoseman i will remove all my try/except from my views..i forgot to do that thanks alot sir

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible,  you said it asks " for instance of that table which has foriegn key bound" means you need instance of foreign key object.. you are trying to assign values. you can do it in below ways.

get the user type like

```
usertype = UserType.objects.get(type=request.POST.get('userType'))
```

and make your insert query like

```
masterCmsUser = MasterCmsUser(userId=authUser,userTypeId=usertype,status=cmsStatus,isDelete=cmsDelete)
```